# Setting Emacs Frame Title in .emacs

Tags: emacs

When I run, `M-x, <RET>, set-frame-title`, I am able to change the title of an Emacs frame to whatever I want.

However, I am trying to do this programmatically from within the `.emacs` file. In particular, I have been trying to do something like this, but to no avail.

```
(setq frame-title-format '("new title here"))
```

How can I set the frame title from within the ELisp?

Comment: Here is a link to a related thread that shows how to use the function `set-frame-name` and also how to add a name/title parameter when creating a frame:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/41318/2287

Answer (score 1):

The doc for [`frame-title-format`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Frame-Titles.html) says:

> It is used only on frames for which no explicit name has been set (see ‘modify-frame-parameters’).

There is no function `set-frame-title` in Emacs, but, if there were, it would have been probably using [`modify-frame-parameters`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Parameter-Access.html) ;-)

Comment: Where does `set-frame-title` that I use come from? Is that some extension?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: do `C-h f set-frame-title RET` and in the `*Help*` buffer there will be a clickable location of the function definition.

Comment: The function `set-frame-name` is defined in `frame.el` -- perhaps that is it.

Comment: There is no `set-frame-title` in [`frame.el`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/frame.el).

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few copy and paste options with links to the actual string substitutions .

Option 1:  is better for buffers like *scratch* that are temporary and don't exist on the filesystem.

Option 2:  gives the absolute path to the file plus the major mode.

Option 3:  is the most direct and contains both the string literal plus the buffer name by %-Construct.

```
(setq frame-title-format
  (concat "%b - emacs@" (system-name)))

(setq-default frame-title-format '("%f [%m]"))

(setq frame-title-format "New title here - %b " )
```

Option 2 was pulled from here: [emacs-stackexchange answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16834/how-to-change-the-title-from-emacshost-to-file-name)

String substitutions are know as  [%-Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/_0025_002dConstructs.html#g_t_0025_002dConstructs) , you have a lot of choices for what variables you'd like in the title. You can also find more information using the links @sds provided.